# How to properly call a url that came from an object ID in django

Tags: django

I want to make a checkout page and also want to call a url which came from an object ID in Django. The products app has its own urls.py, My question is How do you properly call an object ID? .  This is the url  http://localhost:8000/products/1. I attempt to call it but it return some error.

```
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-shopping-
   cart">  </i>  <a href="{% url 'products/1' %}"> Add To Cart  </a>
   </button> 

  urls.py-products 
     url(r'^$', ProductListView.as_view(), name='products'),
     url(r'^cbv/(?P<pk>\d+)', ProductDetailView.as_view(), 
     name='product_detail'),
     url(r'^(?P<id>\d+)', 'products.views.product_detail_view_func', 
     name='product_detail_function'),

  main urls.py
  url(r'^products/', include('products.urls')),

  this is the error

 **Reverse for 'products/1' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' 
 not 
 found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []**
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `url` template tag incorrectly. Try

```
{% url 'product_detail_function' id=1 %}
```

or better pass the object id dynamically ie.

```
 {% url 'product_detail_function' id=my_id %}
```

See [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#url) for details